# How to not show tooltip when click the button immediately?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

**UPDATE**: It seems likes an UX issue, I created an issue on GitHub, you can track here:

https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/910#issuecomment-374369572

---

I am using Reactstrap.

I want to show tooltip only when after hovering mouse 2 seconds. When I click the button immediately, I don't want it be shown.

But right now when I click the button immediately, it shows the tooltip.

I tried both controlled `Tooltip` and `UncontrolledTooltip`, but neither works.

For `Tooltip`, I tried to add `onClick={() => {}}`, but also does not help.

How to not show tooltip when click the button immediately? Thanks

<kbd>[Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/wz70vo15ww)</kbd>

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isTooltipOpen: false
    };
  }

  onToggleTooltip = () => {
    const { isTooltipOpen } = this.state;
    this.setState({ isTooltipOpen: !isTooltipOpen });
  };

  render() {
    const { isTooltipOpen } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          <button id="controlledTooltip">Controlled Tooltip</button>
        </p>
        <p>
          <button id="uncontrolledTooltip">Uncontrolled Tooltip</button>
        </p>

        <Tooltip
          delay={{ show: 2000, hide: 0 }}
          isOpen={isTooltipOpen}
          placement="right"
          target="controlledTooltip"
          toggle={this.onToggleTooltip}
          // onClick={() => {}}
        >
          Discard draft
        </Tooltip>

        <UncontrolledTooltip
          placement="right"
          target="uncontrolledTooltip"
          delay={{ show: 2000, hide: 0 }}
        >
          Hello world!
        </UncontrolledTooltip>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the setTimeOut() function. To prevent loosing context (this), use the arrow function as a simple way to preserve proper execution context.

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({ isTooltipOpen: !isTooltipOpen });
}, 2000);
```

See updated, working, example: https://codesandbox.io/s/j4ojkyv3l3

You can also take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hover-observer. This is a React component that notifies its children of hover interactions. 
It also supports delayed hover and hover-off, which can help reduce unintentional triggering.

Comment: The answer does NOT address the "prevent tooltip from opening on click" part.

Answer (score 0):

As in the github issue linked by you it was mentioned that in version ^8.2.0 there is a `trigger` property. So you can pass `trigger="hover focus"` and omit `"click"` now. That worked fine for me.